# Forced and premature exit from recursion (investigate) in JavaScript (+React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, recursion, error-handling

I have an interesting desire to know a way to break the recursion before it "freezes" the browser and exhausts all resources.

A banal example is just such a cycle:

```
while (true) {
    console.log('Test');
}
```

After a few seconds, the browser already becomes unmanageable, and after a few minutes it restarts.
You can see this error too:

```
net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
```

QUESTION: Is it possible to somehow track the execution of recursion in order to stop it at the worst moment and return the browser to working capacity?
At the same time, I want this to be a universal method, since the browser resources are different (I mean that exit after the nth iteration or second will not work here).

Comment: You can use a counter to count, how many time the body of cycle has been called. If count is greater than MAX_COUNT, you just break the cycle.

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov As I said, it's not the universal method.

Comment: `while (true)` is an infinite loop, not recursion. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @ggorlen As i wrote, it's just an example. Doesn't matter what will bw in the function. 
But if we take this example I want to accomplish the loop.

Comment: I'd say it probably does, because long computations must be broken up into pieces so that the browser doesn't hang. You can't detect the browser hanging, then preemptively do something to not hang it. That hanging point is totally system-specific, so your job as a JS developer is to ensure that the browser has a chance to rerender regularly, as often as possible. But I can't say how you might go about doing this in your case without more details about what you're really trying to accomplish. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: BTW, `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` is not something that should happen likely as a result of a simple `console.log`. You're probably allocating memory in this loop, so the code isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen okay, let's take another example

    `useEffect(()=>{
        const request = () => {
            fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(commits => console.log('commiy -->', commits[0].author.login));
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            setTimeout(request, 5);
        }
    },[])`

Comment: This should be an [edit] to the post, but I can say that the code is probably still not realistic because you're only printing the result -- usually, you set state. Either way, the loop doesn't really make sense-- you're initiating 100000 requests to fire all at the same time in 5 ms rather than what I think you want to do, which is to fire 100000 requests in 5 second intervals, one after the other, over time.